# Find a function $g$ that makes $f$ continuous, but not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Consider the function  $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined piecewise by \begin{align*}f(x) = \begin{cases}0: -1 \leq x < 0 \\ g(x): 0\leq x \leq 1 \end{cases}\end{align*} where $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is some function. Suppose $g$ is a non-zero function given by $$g(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3.$$ Find non-negative real numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ (not all of which are 0) such that $f$ is continuous but not differentiable.

I've been able to find some examples of general continuous, but not differentiable functions, but I have not been able to find one that fits this specific example AND to supply non-negative real numbers that makes it true. My problem is I can't preserve continuity at $f(0)$ but make $f(x)$ non-differentiable given the restriction of the $a_i$'s.

Comment: Do you know under what circumstances would $f$ would be continuous but not differentiable? Especially at $0$?

Comment: "I can't preserve continuity and $f(0)$ but make $f(x)$ non-differentiable" - well, it's easier to make something continuous than it is to make it differentiable.  If you just think about continuity and forget about differentiability you'll probably have an example. Hint: why not try a linear function?

Comment: $f$ won't be differentiable if the limits approaching 0 (from the right and left) are not the same? For example I know that if $g(x) = |x|$, the function would be continuous but not differentiable at $f(0)$. However, I wouldn't be able to supply explicit $a_i$ values which the problem seemed to want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $g(x) = x+x^2$? $g(0)=0$ and $g^\prime(0) = 1 \neq 0$ so $f$ is continuous at $0$ but not differentiable at that point.

By the way any $g(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ with $a_0= 0, \ a_1 \neq 0$ and $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ non-negative would work.

Comment: $g(x)=x$ is simpler

Comment: I can see why that would not be differentiable, but how do I satisfy "finding non-negative real numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$" part?

Comment: $0, 1, 1, 0$ are all non-negative.

Comment: Sorry, I don't find this answer very pedagogical. How have you arrived to this function?

Comment: @Miguel Whatever $g(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ with $a_0= 0, \ a_1 \neq 0$ would work. The one I picked up is my preferred one as I like the prime number $2$ .

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I guess that the OP would appreciate how you get to the conditions $a_0=0$, $a_1\neq 0$ (and the conditions themselves, to begin with).

Comment: @Miguel Please provide a detailed answer if you wish.